# Hybrid tcp::iostream and socket operation with Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

## Context

Firstly some context: A Boost.Asio server receives requests formatted as follow:

- X bytes of metadata in XML
- X bytes of optional binary data

We have a XML parser that takes a std::istream so it's really easy to just pass tcp::iostream to this function. The binary data that follows can be heavy, so we should asynchronously read packets of —say 500ko— until we read all the data.

## Questions

Can we use the tcp::iostream first and then use an async_read with the underlining socket_streambuf? Of course, it's ok for the compilation, but does the read operation on socket correctly use the internal buffer of the tcp::iostream? (That could be not empty even after having read the metadata). I guess it should respect the Liskov Substitution Principle, but I prefer to be sure.

Can we switch from one method to another, where/whenever we want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I didn't used the stream at all. They seemed to be easy/friendly to use, but they doesn't allow asynchronous operations. I realized that mixing synchronous and asynchronous operations was not a good idea. Adding asynchronous operation to the queue help to balance the load of the server. Conclusion: You should only use asynchronous operations because Boost.Asio is mainly designed for them.